# Is it possible to evaluate a Postgres expression without connecting to a database?

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath

PostgreSQL has excellent support for evaluating JSONPath expressions against JSON data.

For example, this query returns `true` because the value of the nested field is indeed "foo".

```sql
select '{"header": {"nested": "foo"}}'::jsonb @? '$.header ? (@.nested == "foo")'
```

Notably this query does not reference any schemas or tables. Ideally, I would like to use this functionality of PostgreSQL without creating or connecting to a full database instance. Is it possible to run PostgreSQL in such a way that it doesn't have schemas or tables, but is still able to evaluate "standalone" queries?

Some other context on the project, we need to evaluate JSONPath expressions against JSON data in both a Postgres database and Python application. Unfortunately, Python does not have any JSONPath libraries that support enough of the spec to be useful to us.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Disappointing, but unsurprising. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I would like to use this functionality of PostgreSQL without creating or connecting to a full database instance.

Well, it is open source.  You can always pull out the source code for this functionality you want and adapt it to compile by itself.  But that seems like a large and annoying undertaking, and I probably wouldn't do it.  And short of that, no.

Why do you need this?  Are you worried about scalability or ease of installation or performance or what?  If you are already using PostgreSQL anyway, firing up a dummy connection to just fire some queries at the JSONB engine doesn't seem too hard.